# Why it modify the memory address?

Tags: c, gtk

I have this sequence of code:

```
printf("%p\n", gameGUI);
printf("label %p\n", gameGUI->labelRoundType);
gui_setRoundType(gameGUI->labelRoundType,
                 gameGUI->game->rounds[roundId]);
printf("label %p\n", gameGUI->labelRoundType);
printf("%p\n", gameGUI);
```

The code of the function gui_setRoundType.

```
int gui_setRoundType(GtkWidget *roundTypeLabel, struct Round *round)
{
    if (round == NULL)
        return ROUND_NULL;
    if (roundTypeLabel == NULL)
        return POINTER_NULL;

    char type[1] = { '\0' };
    intToChar(round->roundType, type);
    gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(roundTypeLabel), type);

    return NO_ERROR;
}
```

The code of GameGUI structure:

```
struct GameGUI {
    struct Game *game;
    struct Select *select;
    struct PlayerCards *playerCards;
    struct PlayersGUI *playersGUI;
    struct CardsFromTable *cardsFromTable;
    struct BidGUI *bidGUI;
    GtkWidget *windowTable;
    GtkWidget *fixedTable;
    GtkWidget *buttonShowScore;
    GtkWidget *imageTrump;
    GtkWidget *labelRoundType;
    GtkWidget *labelNoOfBids;
    GtkWidget *buttonStart;
    int bidPlayerId;
    int cardPlayerId;
};
```

My question is: why it modify the memory address of gameGUI variable after what is called gui_setRoundType() ?

Example of output:

```
0x1e8ff80
label 0x1e9dd50
label 0xcf9
0x1e8ff00
```

This is code of intToChar function.

```
int intToChar(int number, char *string)
{
    int i, copy, j;
    char ch;

    if ((copy = number) < 0)
        number = -number;

    i = 0;
    do {
        string[i++] = number % 10 + '0';
    } while ((number /= 10) > 0);

    if (copy < 0)
        string[i++] = '-';
    string[i] = '\0';

    for (i = 0, j = strlen(string) - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        ch = string[i];
        string[i] = string[j];
        string[j] = ch;
    }

    return NO_ERROR;
}
```

Comment: What does your `intToChar` function do ? Are you sure it doesn't overflow the passed in buffer ? Since the buffer you pass in only has room for 1 element, it is rather useless and can never hold any text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have buffer overrun in `intToChar` function - you pass to it the buffer `type` of the length 1 and in the function you potentially write out of the bounds of this buffer. This triggers undefined behaviour and your pointers start to change randomly.

Comment: roundType is always a digit.

Comment: Even for a digit you need buffer of length 2 for the zero termination which you add in the line `string[i] = '\0';`

Comment: If the length is 2 works perfectly. Thanks for help.